# Why isn't my Jquery closest function working

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this function:

```
var test = $('#currentCat').closest('div');
alert(test);
```

And here is the HTML

```
<div class="collapse" id="26">
   <a href="#" class="list-group-item" id="currentCat">Hoodies (6)</a>
</div>
```

But instead of giving me HTMLDivElement I get Object and it's not working

Comment: Don't use `alert` for debugging your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var test = $('#currentCat').closest('div');
```

jQuery does not return DOM elements.  It returns a jQuery object, which is also an array, which CONTAINS DOM elements.

Do this:

```
var $list = $('#currentCat').closest('div');
var element=$list[0]; // Get first item from the array
console.log(element);
```

Pro debugging hint:

Next time you have a question like this, examine the contents you're looking at.
Had you done a `console.log(test)`, you could have seen it was an array (or array-like) structure.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick! It's working now.
And thank you for that debugging hint. I have always used alert for debugging since I thought it returns the same data.

Comment: @Dope: `alert` converts its argument to a string. That doesn't work well for complex data structures.

Comment: @Dope `console.log` shows very different information that `alert` does...  As Felix mentioned, it converts data to a string.